# Base ten representation proof

Tags: number-theory, number-systems

I want to prove that the pattern repeats but I can't figure out how..

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

[image]

Comment: By cases. Let $n=3k+i$ where $i=0,1,2$ and $k$ is an arbitrary positive integer.

Comment: The pattern repeats simply because of $10^3\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ 37\ )$. Because of this we have $10^{3m+n}=(10^3)^m10^n\equiv 10^n\ (\ mod\ 37\ )$, so we can reduce the exponent modulo $3$.